# behavior of int_[arr] when int_ is reassigned to it's current value

Tags: c, printf

Consider the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define printarr(a,len) iter = 0;while( iter < len )printf("%i ",*(a + iter++));printf("\n");
#define print(a) printf("%s\n",#a);
#define doexp(a); printf("%s:",#a);a;if( strstr(#a,"scanf") == NULL )printf("\n");

int main()
{
int a[10],b[10] = {},iter = 1;
printarr(a,10);
printarr(b,10);
scanf("%i",&iter[a]);
iter = 1;
printf("%i i = %i\n",iter[a],iter);

if( &iter[a] == &a[iter] )
{
 printf("true\n");
 if( iter[a] == a[iter] )
 {
  printf("true!!\n");
 }
}

return 0;
}
```

prints the value I entered for iter[a].

But when I reassign 1 to iter by un-commenting `//doexp( iter = 1 );`

it prints junk for the value of iter[a];

at the statement `doexp( printf("%i i = %i\n",iter[a],iter) );`.

I tried a[iter] instead of a[iter], but got the same result.;

Using gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Why does this happen ?

Comment: There's a reason that using macros for almost anything than named constants is discouraged. It makes code unreadable.

Comment: @Joachim I do agree. But whenever I posted a piece of code related to my question, I was asked to post the whole program to which the code belonged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doexp(scanf...` is 'invoked' when `iter` is 10 (`printarr` makes iter=10). So you are reading the value into a[10] which is outside the array. It's already undefined behavior, and you are just lucky your program doesn't crash at this point.

Printing out `a[1]` will give you a junk value anyway since the item has not been initialized.